# Pivot combo box table in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I am using this SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Max(table1.[quiz]) AS MaxOfquiz
SELECT table1.[quizdate], table1.[studentname], Max(table1.[quiz]) AS [Total Of 
quizscores]
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.[quizdate], table1.[studentname]
PIVOT table1.[coursename];
```

To try and pivot a combobox table:

**Table1**

```
ID  quizdate    coursename  studentname quiz
1   02-Jan-21   math        john        100    
2   03-Feb-21   science     joe         99     
3   04-Mar-21   physics     monica      97      
4   05-Apr-20   language    mike        88
```

Where coursename is a dropdown (math, science, physics, language) into

**Table 2**

```
studentname math science physics language
john        100
joe               99
monica                   97
mike                             88
```

I got these results:

```
quizdate    studentname Total Of quizscores 1   2   3   4
4/4/2016    moe         88                          88  
1/1/2017    john       100                              100
2/2/2017    joe         99                      99      
3/3/2017    monica      97                  97
```

It seems that combox box coursename can't be pivoted as column name, but the
numbers instead. Can anyone explain how I can generate the correct results?

Comment: Why would you even want to use a CROSSTAB query as the RowSource for a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

You answer it yourself:

> Where coursename is a dropdown (math, science, physics, language)

So, in the query, the value from the field will be the ID of these "dropdowns".

To obtain coursenames, move these to a separate table and join this with Table1 in your query.

Comment: The reason is a drop down (combo box) due to these coursenames are lookup from another table. Hence, coursename data type is number, and can't be changed to short text due to the relationship.

Comment: The reason that i need to use pivot table due to I need to create a report such as  Student Name Course Name Course Name Course Name Course Name Course Name Course Name
1  Date Attended Date Attended Date Attended Date Attended Date Attended Date Attended
  Quiz Score(s) Quiz Score(s) Quiz Score(s) Quiz Score(s) Quiz Score(s) Quiz Score(s)

Comment: Well, then join that "another table" which holds the coursenames.